# svgmin outputs empty svg file?

Tags: svg, gruntjs, minify

I just installed svgo and then svgmin with grunt. Instead of minifying my code, when I run the svgmin command it just outputs a 0 kb file with no content. The task itself is registered in my gruntfile and runs successfully in the console.

My gruntfile has this function...

```
svgmin: { //minimize SVG files
        options: {
            plugins: [
                { removeViewBox: false },
                { removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false }
            ]
        },
        dist: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'main/svg',
            src: ['*.svg'],
            dest: 'main/svg',
            ext: '.success.svg'
        }
    },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means your svg was only made of garbage code. Nothing to do. :D

Comment: I'm having the same problem and my SVG file couldn't be simpler. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, the solution is quite easy actually. You just need to set the plugin `cleanupIDs` to `false`:

```
options: {
        plugins: [
            { cleanupIDs: false },
            { removeViewBox: false },
            { removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false }
        ]
    },
```

It seems that the `cleanupIDs` plugin removes all groups (`<g>`) and symbols (`<symbol>`) that contain IDs, instead of just removing the IDs. Once you set it to false, you'll be grand.

Hope that helps.